# Suggesting 'misconception' tag

Tags: discussion

I don't have sufficient rep to add tags... I suggest `misconceptions` or `alternative-conceptions` for questions I've posed:

- [Teaching "math equality" vs. "CS assignment" vs. "CS equality logic operator"](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/teaching-math-equality-vs-cs-assignment-vs-cs-equality-logic-operator)
- [Teaching "CS integer" vs. "math integer"](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/teaching-cs-integer-vs-math-integer)
- [Teaching "math function" vs. "CS function"](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/teaching-math-function-vs-cs-function)

Comment: Hi Bennett! You seem to be interested in working out the scope of the site. Would you be interested in joining some of the other users [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/), where we discuss issues such as this one?

Comment: @thesecretmaster Wow, the first 47 times I read your comment, I was certain that it said "working *outside* the scope of the site". Gotta watch that mental autocorrect thing like a hock.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced it would be a good tag to have. Tagging is useful so that people interested in a topic (or with expertise in said topic) can subscribe and search for questions which interest them. 'Misconceptions' don't really have much in common, so I don't think it'd make the best tag (it would seem to be more like a 'meta tag', like [subjective](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective) or [beginner](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) on Stack Overflow).

I think the tagging you used is generally okay as it is. [introductory-programming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introductory-programming) is being considered for removal though, so you might want to use another tag instead.

Comment: Well...asking about common student misconceptions or how to fix a particular misconception all seem very much on-topic. I'm not sure if the tag is necessary, but I'm also not convinced it's a meta tag.

Comment: Tagging also helps askers to know what is on topic and how to frame a question, which is why I asked my questions here about the differentiation and equity tags. For new sites, establishing the tags is probably the most important task. Like when my co-instructor said, "The Properties *are* the Class."

Answer (score 0):

I used to put a lot of effort in to explaining that there is a conceptual level to all aspects of computing, such as in database design. But the students by and large didn't get it, much like here with your idea of the tag.

Maybe a better idea for a tag like this will occur to you that will be accepted later on.